# How to say in a compact way: an increase of something is due to decrease in something else

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I am examining temporal trends in the sale numbers of apples, pears and bananas. And I found a significant 5 percentage point **increase for apples** and a significant 5 percentage point **decrease for bananas**. The sales of pears remained constant during the observed time period.

What is a better and more compact way for saying the following:

> There was an increase in the sales of apples, simultaneously decreasing the number of bananas.

What is a good word for saying that apples increase can be attributed to the decrease of bananas?

Comment: Note that 'There was an increase in the sales of apples, simultaneously decreasing the number of bananas' claims causality. A lot more research needs to be done to corroborate this claim. Differential supplies might have been the true explanation.

Comment: This is made difficult to answer by the sheer implausibility of the assertion and the paucity of the evidence. One thing has trended up, another down. You want to say there is a causal relationship in one direction (that one "can be attributed" to the other). The following questions arise: (1) Why suppose there is a causal relationship at all? Correlation does not entail causation. (2) If it's a causal relationship, why suppose it goes from bananas to apples and not the other way around?. (3) Are you merely trying to summarise survey results or to create theories of fruit consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

**This answer doesn't do justice to the demand of the question and I suggest that OP wait for the definitive answer. In fact, as has been brought to my notice by some enlightened members here, this answer is technically wrong.**

I think **inversely proportional** is the term you're looking for.

> [Pear sales being constant], apples sales were **inversely proportional** to banana sales— [the former registering a 5% increase, and the latter a 5% decrease.]

You could do away with the bracketed elements depending on what you wish to keep and what you wish to omit.

Thanks to @Jim for suggesting that I reconsider fine-tuning my answer to meet precisely the demand of the question.

Comment: That does not include the notion that it’s a causal relationship.

Comment: An inverse relationship is a bit general (When apples go up, bananas go down.) Here, all we know is that banana sales suffered from apple sales "during the observed time period." Also, no disrespect, removing the word "I" from an answer displays more an authoritative answer and less a personal opinion.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Thanks for the suggestion. Will keep this thing in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The briefest statement may be :

*Apple and banana sales were negatively correlated.*

> Correlate = to establish a mutual or reciprocal relation between
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correlate)

In positive correlation, both increase or decrease together; in negative correlation, one increases as the other decreases.

> negative correlation means that there is an inverse relationship between two variables - when one variable decreases, the other increases.
>
> [Your dictionary](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/negative-correlation-examples.html)

Comment: But that doesn't give the actual figure of 5%. And this might be something OP wishes to retain in the statement.

Comment: @user405662 the questioner in asking for “a better way” or “a good word” and does not mention retention of the 5%. Should they wish to retain that example number, is is easy to add to the answer in a quantitative way.

Comment: Actually "inversely proportional" also doesn't entail that if one thing goes up by 5% the other goes down by 5% (or to put it another way, multiplying by 1.05 and multiplying by 0.95 are not the inverse of each other).

Comment: Inversely proportionality has not been discussed so far. It is in any case not synonymous with an inverse relationship. Relationship does not imply proportionality. But we digress.

Comment: Sorry Anton. While "inversely proportional" wasn't discussed under your answer, it was separately proposed as the answer by @user405662. My comment was a response to user405662 suggesting that if his comment in response to you is valid, it's also a valid criticism of his own answer.

Comment: @Steve Lovell— Fair point. Is it because of the percentage involved that my answer isn't quite right? I guess so. Were it simply _one increases by 5 **points** and the other decreases by as many points_, my answer would probably hold, right?

Comment: @user405662. If X and Y are inversely proportional then X = k / Y for some constant k. This entails that X * Y = k. Suppose a rectangle has a fixed area. The width and length become inversely proportional. If one side decreases by 50% then to maintain the same area, the other side must double in length, i.e. increase by 100%, not increase by 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler is always better in this kind of writing. You don’t want to waste your reader’s mental energy in *decoding your language* when it should be applied to *grasping your argument* (whatever it happens to be).

Sales that period: Apples up.  Bananas down.  Five percent each way. Pears went sideways.